# Studying primes via the gamma function alone: $(x+1)\prod_n \Gamma(\frac{x}{n}+1)^{\mu(n)}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables

Various questions on MO concerning the "surprise" occurrence of the gamma function in the functional equation of the Riemann zeta function got me wondering whether the Gamma function alone suffice for an analytic formulation of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Pondering this lead me to consider the product

$$(x+1)\prod_n \Gamma\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{\mu(n)}$$

whose convergence is apparently equivalent to the prime number theorem.  (Fix $x\not=0,-1$, apply $\ln$ and linearize to get a series that eventually behaves like $1 - 1/2 - 1/3 -1/5 + 1/6 - 1/7 +\cdots$.)  The limit appears to equal $e^x$.

Of course my motivation lay in using Mobius-type inclusion-exclusion to eliminate one by one
all the poles.

My question: does this expression occur in the literature?

Comment: Wait--fundamental theorem of arithmetic, or prime number theorem?

Comment: David, the function that you consider is quite interesting. Have you considered that it is based on the product definition of the the $\Gamma(x)$ and the limit form of $e^x$? You also might want to consider the multiplication theorem found at

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem

Some modification of this theorem might help. If none of this helps then you might want to prove that the function has no roots. Please get back to us on this. Your function is interesting and I haven't seen it in the literature, so I would advise that you definitely keep working on it :)

Comment: What is $\mu (n)$?

Comment: @Daniel and Anixx  $\mu(n)$ is the Mobius function:  -1 to the number of prime factors of a square-free number, 0 for numbers divisible by a square.

Comment: Thanks Joe! Yes the idea is that the poles of log gamma line up like the positive integers themselves, so one can get multiplicative identities from combinatorial identities. The multiplication theorems you pointed me to were in my mind, and best understood I think in terms of expressing the sequence of poles of log gamma in two different ways - and here I'm just playing a more complicated version of the game. After a night's sleep, I believe I understand the 
$e^x$. For $x$ a large integer one plays inclusion-exclusion with
the factors of $x!$. In the end one needs $d/dx 1/\zeta(z)$ at $z=1.$

Comment: @Daniel Litt  The gradual disappearance of all the poles as you multiply out the produce reflects the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.  The fact that the infinite product actually converges
for every $x$ (indeed the fact that it converges for any $x\not=0$) reflects the prime number theorem.  